# Determining number of days between dates PineScript

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to determine the number of days between dates to use in the plot function.

```
var Start1 = (timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), 00, 00) - timestamp(2019, 12, 19, 12, 00)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
plot(gr, color=color.red, show_last = Start1)
```

Error:

```
line 21: Cannot call 'plot' with argument 'show_last'='Start1'. An argument of 'series int' type was used but a 'input int' is expected
```

Kindly assist to make a workaround.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

````
var int Start1 = (timestamp(year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), 00, 00) - timestamp(2019, 12, 19, 12, 00)) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
int toto = int(Start1)

test = last_bar_index - bar_index <= toto
plot(test ? toto : na, color=color.red)
```
````

Comment: It doesn't work either. Same result.

Comment: you're correct, I've been trying a few things on my end, I did find an alternative though

Comment: I edited my original answer